# eBay: comparing similar items

Tags: ebay-api

I am developing an application which compares our items with competitors' items for prices, etc.
Is there a way to search similar items?
Currently we can do that manually using keywords but it's so tedious.
We have 2000 auto part items.

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: Non-technical issue: If you are an eBay-user you may need their written consent to automate this. Read about robots in http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/user-agreement.html . If you are not an eBay-user, it is still etiquette to respect the robots.txt, which seems restrictive.

Comment: More specifically, is the question about [tag:fuzzy-comparison] and [tag:approximate] or [tag:web-scraping]

Comment: It's about fuzzy-comparison and approximate. Not web-scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You need [getSimilarItems()](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchandising/docs/callref/getSimilarItems.html) in the eBay Merchandising API. It takes eBay itemId and returns a list of items similar to that item.

Comment: Wow. Why didn't I know that? Thanks much.